# Addition of Two Numbers In Assembly

Tags: windows, assembly

So I have this code here were I'm trying to add two numbers in it but I can't seem to get the output from this code that I've been trying do for a while. :

```
 section    .text
    global _start       ;must be declared for using gcc
_start:                     ;tell linker entry point
    mov edx, '6'  
    sub edx,'0'
    
    mov ecx ,'7'
    sub ecx,'0'
    add edx,ecx 
    

    
    mov [math_sum], edx 
    mov eax,msg 
    mov ebx, len
    mov ecx,1
    mov edx,4
    
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax,math_sum
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,1
    mov edx,4
    int 0x80
    
    mov edx,1 
    int 0x80
    
section .data
    
msg db "Sum of 6 and 7 is:"
len equ $ - msg 

segment .bss

math_sum resb 2
```

I'm getting  Segmentation fault but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Your code looks like 32-bit Linux but you tagged this Windows. Which is correct?

Comment: Why are you putting in an (ASCII? '6') then subtracting an ASCII '0" from it to put a 6 in a register?  That seems awfully roundabout.

Comment: `mov [math_sum], edx`: 4 byte store.  `math_sum resb 2`: uh oh.

Comment: If it's supposed to be Linux then you have the system call conventions all wrong.  For example `eax` is supposed to contain the system call number.